# GPU usage monitoring on OSX

Tags: osx, monitoring, logs, gpu, gpu-monitor

I have a Macbook Pro, and I am currently looking for software which is suitable for monitoring the Graphics card usage of the Intel Iris Graphics 6100 that the Macbook makes use of. Is there some sort of application which offers GPU usage logging capabilities, or else a command which I can type into the terminal to create GPU usage logs?

Thank you

Comment: Are [any of these suggestions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/gpu-usage-monitoring-cuda) of use? (From Unix & Linux, so maybe not....)

Answer (score 1):

I use **iStat Menu Meters** for this on Mac OS: I do a lot of 3D work and renders, which can tax my system pretty heavily so I keep track of CPU, GPU, & RAM.

Does what it says on the tin - super useful, small footprint and fast.

Highly recommend - no I'm in no way affiliated - just a longtime user.

https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

Answer (score -1):

iStat is for me one of the best apps to buy on Mac. But when you are looking for a cheaper solution there is a Fork [MenuMeters](https://github.com/yujitach/MenuMeters) from [this one](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menu). This can do the same things, but is larger in your menu bar.